# FOSUserBundle no encoder has been configured : creating a new user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i would like to create a new user in FOSUserBundle (Symfony2), but i always get the same message (i'm using `php app/console fos:user:create` ) :

> No encoder has been configured for account "MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User".

the imports are in the right order

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        //...
        new MyProject\UserBundle\MyProjectUserBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    );
```

the security file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

but i'm always getting the same error... Do you know how to fix this? The [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258767/sf2-fos-userbundle-cant-create-user-no-encoder-configured)
is not working for me

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are missing your own user's class in the encoders configuration, for example:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

Alternatively you can match it on the FOSUserBundle interface like so:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

Comment: thanks ! it works, i also had to use `php -c` then the path to usr > private > php.ini with `date.timezone` and finally create the user. Thanks Seldaek!

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony 2.7+ you should use this configuration:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
```

BUT! you also should have PHP 5.5 and Apache 2.4 or Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

edit security.yml in app/config

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```

under main add "logout: ~" as well

For Symfony 4.x see https://youtu.be/QgYQWGwY9tM